# solving $x^2+y^2+z^2=3xyz-4$ in prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Solve in prime numbers the question
**PRIME NUMBERS**

junior problem
**proposed by Adrian Andreescu, Dallas Texas USA**

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=3xyz-4$$

Comment: Hint: Analyze the equation modulo 3.

Comment: Also maybe mod 4 could help.

Comment: I couldn't do this way @Florian

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, start by analysing the equation modulo $3$.$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2\pmod3$$

The squares in $\mathbb{F}^3$ are $0$ and $1$. This tells us that exactly one of the squares on the left side is equal to $0$ modulo $3$, so without loss of generality we can assume $x=0\pmod3$, and $y,z\neq0\pmod3$.

Since $x,y,z$ are primes numbers, this means that $x=3$. Thus the original equation becomes
$$9+y^2+z^2=9yz-4\iff y^2+z^2=9yz-13.$$
Now you should be able to solve this equation, for example you can try to express $z$ in terms of $y$, and then only take the integer solutions, keeping in mind that $y\neq3\neq z$.

Comment: thanks)) but I don't understand first part why equal to two? can you explain pls

Comment: $3=0\pmod3$ so $3xyz=0\pmod3$ and $-4=2\pmod3$

Comment: I hope you don't mind; if you do, please do a rollback.

Comment: i can't do anything after that(( help me

Comment: I realised this question is part of a contest whichis not finished yet so I won't respond to this topic anymore

Comment: no this question is my homework ,not anything more and i must do for that i  need your help